# How can I do SQL query based on two conditions on two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

[see the EARD scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mWgn.png)

Major_applied_for table

| id | preference | application_number (fk) | major_code (fk) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Some Clarifications:

• The code attribute of Major table holds (1)CS for computer science, (2)BMS for business management and so on.

• preference attribute of Major_Applied_For is 1, 2 or 3 (1 for being the first
choice, 2 being the second choice and 3 being the third choice)
.
.
.

This is a table that many to many relationship resolved in, I wanna get all the application numbers that have CS as the first choice and BMS as the second choice.

I tried this sql statement but it's logically incorrect.

SELECT m.id, CONCAT(m.fname, " ", m.lname) AS Fullname, app.number AS application_no
FROM applicant m, application app, major_applied_for mjaf
WHERE ((mjaf.major_code = 1 AND mjaf.preference = 1) AND (mjaf.major_code = 2 AND mjaf.preference = 2) AND (mjaf.application_number = app.number AND app.applicant_id = m.id));

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Post a full data sample for all the tables that are involved.

Comment: I think this might be more straightforward if you use a `JOIN` statement instead of joining the tables in the `WHERE` clause.  But we can't help without knowing what the applicant and application tables look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the applicants with CS as their first pref, find the applicants with BMS their second pref. Inner join these two sets and check their names.

```
with first_cs as (
    select c.applicant_id
    from major_applied_for a inner join major b on a.major_code = b.code and a.preference = 1 and b.name = 'CS'
                             inner join application c on a.application_number = c.number ), second_bms as(
    select c.applicant_id
    from major_applied_for a inner join major b on a.major_code = b.code and a.preference = 2 and b.name = 'BMS'
                             inner join application c on a.application_number = c.number ) select fname,
       lname from first_cs a inner join second_bms b on a.applicant_id = b.applicant_id
                inner join applicant c on a.applicant_id = c.id
```